How to capture the event of a user pressing Ctrl+A to clear a SAP B1 form's fields
I am trying to capture the event of a user pressing Ctrl+A to clear a SAP Business One form's fields when that form is in focus/active.
I have tried the below but it is not catching the event.
if (pVal.FormTypeEx == "CDD" && pVal.EventType == SAPbouiCOM.BoEventTypes.et_KEY_DOWN && pVal.Modifiers == SAPbouiCOM.BoModifiersEnum.mt_CTRL && pVal.CharPressed == 065)
{
    //code
}

How do I accomplish this?
Regards,

Have you tried testing for ASCII 97, lower case A?
